# Define when $y$ is a function of $x$

Tags: calculus, functions

Hello guys I want to make  sure myself  in determming when is  $y$ as function of   $x$,so for this,  let us consider following question. If the equation of circle is given by  this

$$x^2+y^2=25$$
and question is  find the equation of tangent  of circle at point $(3,4)$,then it is clear that we need  calculate the derivative  and also we can  express $ y$ as

$$y=\sqrt{25-x^2}$$
but, let us consider following situation

> $$x^3+y^3=6\cdot x \cdot y$$

it's name is The Folium of Descartes  and my question is  the same : calculate  the equation of the tangent of this  folium at point $(3,4)$.
I know that  somehow expressing  $y$ as a function of $x$ is difficult  but could't we do it by some even long mathematical manipulation? So what  is the strict explanation when is $y$ a  function of $x$ and when is it not? I need to be    educated in this  topic and please explain me ways  of this,thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation $$
\tag{1}x^3+y^3=6xy
$$does define $y$ as a function of $x$ locally (or, rather, it defines $y$ as a function of $x$ implicitly).  Here, it is difficult to write the defining equation  as $y$ in terms of $x$.  But, you don't have to do that to evaluate the value of the derivative of $y$.

[edit] The point $(3,4)$ does not satisfy   equation (1); so there is no tangent line at this point.

Let's, instead,  consider the point $(3,3)$, which does satisfy equation (1):

To find the slope of the tangent line at $(3,3)$, you need to find $y'(3)$. To find this, first
  [implicitly differentiate](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/ImplicitDIff.aspx) both sides of the defining equation for $y$ 
 (equation (1)). This gives 
$$
{d\over dx} (x^3+y^3)={d\over dx} 6xy
$$
So,  using the chain and product rules:
$$
3x^2+3y^2 y' =6y+6x y'.
$$ 
When $x=3$ and $y=3$, you have
$$
3\cdot 3^2+3\cdot 3^2 y'(3)=6\cdot 3+6\cdot 3\cdot y'(3).
$$
Solve this for $y'(3)={3\cdot 3^2-6\cdot 3\over6\cdot3 -3\cdot3^2}=-1.$

Now you can find the equation of the tangent line since you know the slope and that the point  $(3,3)$ is on the line.

---

Generally any "nice" equation in the variables $x$ and $y$ will define $y$ as a function of $x$ in some neighborhood of a given point. Given the $x$ value, the corresponding $y$ value is the solution to the equation ("the" solution in a, perhaps small, neighborhood of the point).

Of course, sometimes it is extremely difficult (if not impossible) to find an *explicit* form of the function; that is, of the form $y=\Phi(x)$ for some expression $\Phi(x)$.  In these cases, to find the derivative of $y$, you have to use the approach above.

Comment: Just to make sure that the OP won't jump to wrong conclusions: The above method works exactly, when we don't need to divide by zero when solving the derivative $y'$ from the above equation. The implicit function theorem then tells exactly what is needed "locally" $y$ can be solved uniquely as a function of $x$. But things may go wrong. If you try this with the folium of Descartes, when $(x,y)=(0,0)$, you will not succeed. The reason is that the folium intersects itself there, and there cannot be a (unique) tangent. You can isolate the two branches with other tricks.